# What's the difference between lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier?

Tags: android, textview, line-spacing

I'm adding line spacing in my textview which spans multiple lines.
What's the difference between `android:lineSpacingExtra` and `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`?

lineSpacingExtra with 2dp worked fine for me but I was wondering what the Multiplier does instead?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The difference is that `android:lineSpacingExtra` add extra spacing between lines of text of TextView and `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` work as scale factor for height of line space. in other words, each line height will be `height*multiplier + extra`

Comment: Height of what ? The text-font? Meaning text-size? This is useful in case the TextView changes its text-size?

Comment: `android:lineSpacingExtra` takes floating number of format dp,sp,px,mm,in

Answer (score 16):

It's rather simple: one is additive and one is multiplicative.

If you have a default line spacing of `LINE_SPACING` and use:

```
float x = 2;
float y = 1.5;
setLineSpacing(x, y);
```

The resulting line spacing will be `1.5*LINE_SPACING + 2`

It is important to note that *the multiplication happens first!* This follows the conventional order of operations (multiplication before addition).

See the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing(float, float)

In the future, it might be wise to look up such documentation first. ;)